# Qualtrics API json error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, api, qualtrics

I have a Python GET API request that passes to json, and an error comes up on this line of my code:

```
data = json.loads(requestDownload.content)
```

Error is : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Object is created via:

```
requestDownloadUrl = baseUrl + fileId + '/file'
requestDownload = requests.request("GET", requestDownloadUrl, headers=headers, stream=True)
```

I took a look at the requestDownload response, which is [200], and the content is in bytes, which I assume passes through json.loads just fine (based on online documentation). However, it doesn't seem to work still. What should I do to troubleshoot this better?

[image: Response and content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content is in bytes, You'll need to decode them into a string before passing them to JSON.

```
data = json.loads(requestDownload.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I applied `data = json.loads(requestDownload.content.decode("utf-8"))` and got a <class 'str'> but still got the same error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error again.

Comment: Could you paste `requestDownload.content` here?

Comment: b'StartDate,EndDate,Status,IPAddress,Progress,Duration (in seconds),Finished,..'

Type is: <class 'str'>

Comment: This doesn't remotely look like a JSON string, are you aware that `json.loads` is only used to convert a JSON string to a dictionary?

Comment: This is what I used to pull the data, and unfortunately I can't copy the whole printed output because of PII and it's just too long for one comment. 

I fixed it by doing this:

   `Try:`
 `data = json.loads(requestDownload.content)`

        `df = json_normalize(data['responses'])`

    `except:`

        `data = requestDownload.content`

        `df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode("utf-8")))`

    `return df`

Comment: Couldn't quite understand why you did that without looking at the content, but happy to see it works :)

Comment: The content shows up in the screenshot I attached to the question.